# Calculator button returns 'undefined', when pressed

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers, calculator

sorry for asking so soon again, this is my second project and I got stuck at this: I'm making a simple calculator with basic operations, and right now, I'm creating the buttons' functions so when they're pressed, the value of the button is input into the calculator screen; my problem is, that the button returns 'undefined', even though I think I'm targeting the right class using document.querySelectorAll().

Again, thank you for helping me, I try no to ask much to be able to solve or at least figure out this stuff by myself, and though I like it and am motivated, i'm starting to feel kinda dumb.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Ysmael's Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        
        <div id="display">
            <input type="text" id="numField"/> 
        </div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                <th><input type="button" value="7" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button7"></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="4" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button4"/></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="1" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button1"/></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonPlus"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="8" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button8"/></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="5" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button5"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="2" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button2"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="-" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonMinus"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="9" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button9"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="6" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button6"></th> 
                    <th><input type="button" value="3" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button3"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="*" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonMultiply"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="0" class="numButton row4 buttons" id="button0"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="." class="decButton row4 buttons" id="buttonDot"></th>
                    <th><button type="submit" value="=" class="equalButton row4 buttons" id="buttonEqual">=</button></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="%" class="opButton row4 buttons" id="buttonDivide"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
```

```
//display//
let calculatorScreen = document.getElementById('numField');
//display//


const numButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numButton');
const opButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.opButton');
const equalButton = document.querySelector('.equalButton');
const dotButton = document.querySelector('.decButton');



//buttons//

//Button funtions//
numButtons.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculatorScreen.value += numButtons.value;
    })
})
```

I tried to input the value of a button, so I expected for the click to do that

Answer (score 0):

`numButtons` is an array, in which the `value` property is `undefined`, but it should be the `button.value` from parameter.

```js
//display//
let calculatorScreen = document.getElementById('numField');
//display//


const numButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numButton');
const opButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.opButton');
const equalButton = document.querySelector('.equalButton');
const dotButton = document.querySelector('.decButton');



//buttons//

//Button funtions//
numButtons.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculatorScreen.value += number.value;
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Ysmael's Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        
        <div id="display">
            <input type="text" id="numField"/> 
        </div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                <th><input type="button" value="7" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button7"></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="4" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button4"/></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="1" class="numButton row1 buttons" id="button1"/></th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonPlus"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="8" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button8"/></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="5" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button5"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="2" class="numButton row2 buttons" id="button2"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="-" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonMinus"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="9" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button9"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="6" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button6"></th> 
                    <th><input type="button" value="3" class="numButton row3 buttons" id="button3"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="*" class="opButton row5 buttons" id="buttonMultiply"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="0" class="numButton row4 buttons" id="button0"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="." class="decButton row4 buttons" id="buttonDot"></th>
                    <th><button type="submit" value="=" class="equalButton row4 buttons" id="buttonEqual">=</button></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="%" class="opButton row4 buttons" id="buttonDivide"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the same class in multiple divs then you will get an array of values.

You can print the `console.log(numButtons.values)` to see the array.

You need to access value like this,

```
numButtons.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculatorScreen.value += number.value;
    })
})
```